# Auto reconnect SignalR client when server restart

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-core-signalr

I work with ASP.NET Core SignalR in the ASP.NET Boilerplate project and everything is ok while the server is up.

But for any reason that I need to restart the server, I see these errors:

[image]

And I have to refresh my web page to reconnect to SignalR.

Is there any way to check the server and reconnect without refreshing?

I use the default SignalR client that comes with the Angular template and ABP v4.0.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed in v5.1.1 of the template: [aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template#498](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/pull/498)

## Reconnect loop

```sh
yarn upgrade abp-web-resources@^4.1.0
```

Reconnect loop was made available in abp-web-resources@4.1.0:

```js
// Reconnect loop
function start() {
    connection.start().catch(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            start();
        }, 5000);
    });
}

// Reconnect if hub disconnects
connection.onclose(function (e) {
    if (e) {
        abp.log.debug('Connection closed with error: ' + e);
    } else {
        abp.log.debug('Disconnected');
    }

    // if (!abp.signalr.autoConnect) {
    if (!abp.signalr.autoReconnect) {
        return;
    }

    // setTimeout(function () {
    //     connection.start();
    // }, 5000);
    start();
});
```

References:

- [aspnetboilerplate/bower-abp-resources@8cf7928](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/bower-abp-resources/commit/8cf7928d4bfd936f5bc4003d9a3a17d89de871ae#diff-319b478abd3b3d6321e1a836e5b86adf) (abp-web-resources@4.1.0)
- [aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate#4490](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/4490) (ABP v4.7.0)

## Reconnect loop + Circuit breaker

```sh
yarn upgrade abp-web-resources@^5.1.1
```

Circuit breaker was made available in abp-web-resources@5.1.1:

```js
// Reconnect loop
function tryReconnect() {
    if (tries > abp.signalr.maxTries) {
        return;
    } else {
        connection.start()
            .then(() => {
                reconnectTime = abp.signalr.reconnectTime;
                tries = 1;
                console.log('Reconnected to SignalR server!');
            }).catch(() => {
                tries += 1;
                reconnectTime *= 2;
                setTimeout(() => tryReconnect(), reconnectTime);
            });
    }
}

// Reconnect if hub disconnects
connection.onclose(function (e) {
    if (e) {
        abp.log.debug('Connection closed with error: ' + e);
    } else {
        abp.log.debug('Disconnected');
    }

    if (!abp.signalr.autoReconnect) {
        return;
    }

    // start();
    tryReconnect();
});
```

References:

- [aspnetboilerplate/bower-abp-resources#22](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/bower-abp-resources/pull/22/files#diff-319b478abd3b3d6321e1a836e5b86adf) (abp-web-resources@5.1.1)
- [aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate#4975](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/4975) (ABP v5.1.0)